# what does the <> operator mean in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking at some legacy code that says

```
If OBRString <> "^^" then
```

What does the `<>` operator mean?

Comment: `!=` means not `=`. it's from old school. `>' means greater than, `<` means less than, so `<>` means greater or less then, means not equal

Comment: http://www.google.ca/#hl=fr&sclient=psy-ab&q=VB+.NET+%22%3C%3E%22+operator&oq=VB+.NET+%22%3C%3E%22+operator&aq=f&aqi=g-L2&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=50939l53886l0l55878l11l11l0l0l0l0l178l1455l0.11l11l0&gs_l=serp.3..0i19l2.50939l53886l0l55878l11l11l0l0l0l0l178l1455l0j11l11l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e7627638e8597ed2&biw=1600&bih=785

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It means "does not equal".

Equivalent c# operator is `!=`

See [Comparison Operators (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx)

Comment: I thought it was `isNot` .. or are they the same?

Comment: @AdorableVB [<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6.aspx) checks for value inequality while [IsNot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx) checks if two object references refer to different objects.

Answer (score 3):

It checks for inequality, so here it checks whether `OBRString` is not equal to `"^^"`.

Answer (score 2):

<> in VB.NET means "not equal to".
It can be used with the normal oprands as well as in comparision with the items when compared with the datas fetched with the data reader (from database).

Answer (score 1):

It determines whether two objects are NOT equal.

Answer (score 0):

distinct.. but you should have probably google that!or not equal if you like better...